# Can Jenkins be configured to run a set of jobs independently from other jobs?

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have the following Maven project setup in SCM:

- A
- B (depends on A)
- C (depends on A and B, builds an archive containing artifacts from A and B)

I have organized Jenkins so there are sets of jobs where A runs, then B, then C. For example, I have a set of builds triggered by SCM commit (mvn clean install), a set of builds which run reports (mvn clean site), and sets of builds which deploy to our development/test/production servers (mvn clean install + run some plugins to deploy).

Problems happen when the jobs run concurrently. For instance:

1. If the C commit job is building the same time as the A commit job, the the C commit job often has trouble reading from the local m2 repo since the A commit job may be writing to the local m2 repo.
2. If the Commit jobs are running the same time as the Deploy jobs, then I am concerned that they are writing to and reading from the same local m2 repo.

Ideally I want to keep the ability to run these sets of jobs concurrently.

1. Currently I am blocking downstream jobs from running when an upstream job is building. That has prevented some issues. However, I still have an issue where C is in the middle of building and then A starts to build. Are there any known issues with enabling both "Block build when upstream project is building" and "Block build when downstream project is building"?
2. Can I configure Jenkins such that a set of jobs use the same Maven repository? For instance, I would like the commit triggered jobs to use one repository and use another repository for the development deploy jobs. Is this the correct solution for what I want or is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question -

You should be able to use both "*Block build when upstream project is building*"
and "*Block build when downstream project is building*" in the same job-configuration.

This will prevent Job-A from starting when Job-B or Job-C are already running,
and will prevent Job-C from starting when Job-A or Job-B are already running.

Cheers

Comment: To answer the second part of my question: Configure related jobs to use the same alternate Maven settings file which defines a custom local repository. Copy your existing settings.xml on the Jenkins server and specify a custom localRepository. Next, Configure each related Jenkins job, under the Build section, select the Advanced button, and enter a relative path for Alternate settings file.

Comment: @BennyMcBenBen you must post your answer as the right solution, please.